# How to map data from smaller table to a larger table in Spark and Cassandra? (Primary key of 1st Table is partition key of 2nd Table)

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, rdd, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector

So here is my table 1:

```
case class Table1(
    key1: String // (primary key),
    value1: String
)
```

table 2:

```
case class Table2(
    key1: String // (partition key)
    key2: String // (primary key)
    value1: String
)
```

I need to copy value1 from table 1 to all rows of the partition (matching key1 from table 1) in table 2.

My code:

```
val table2 = table1.map(
    s => {
        .... // Here code
    }
)
table2.saveToCassandra("keyspaceName", "table2", SomeColumns("
```

Answer (score 1):

Do join between tables and then write data back, something like:

```scala
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._

val df1 = spark.read.cassandraFormat("table1", "ks").load
val df2 = spark.read.cassandraFormat("table2", "ks").load.select("key1", "key2")
val joined = df2.join(df1, df1("key1") === df2("key2"))
  .select(df2("key1"), df2("key2"), df1("value1"))
joined.write.cassandraFormat("table2", "ks").save
```

To make this process efficient, you need to use so-called direct join that is available since Spark Cassandra Connector 2.5.0 (if you have previous versions then you will need to go down to RDD API and use function `.joinWithCassandraTable`).

Direct join is enabled on start of process (`spark-shell` or `spark-submit`), like this:

```sh
bin/spark-shell --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.5.1 \
   --conf spark.sql.extensions=com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraSparkExtensions
```

P.S. You can read more about joining with Cassandra in the [following blog post](https://alexott.blogspot.com/2020/07/spark-effective-joins-with-cassandra.html).

Comment: Is it possible to join using RDD? I am using spark.cassandraTable("ks", "table1") (spark is the spark context)

Comment: yes, that's what I mean by `.joinWithCassandraTable` function. I have a code for it in the blog post, and here is documentation: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md#performing-efficient-joins-with-cassandra-tables-since-12